# Placing Magento in a subdirectory does not work

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

I have a rule in `/root/.htaccess` which rewrites mydomain.com/shop to my `/root/magento/` directory:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ magento/$1      [L]
RewriteRule ^shop magento/index.php
```

But this causes Magento to generate a '404 Not Found' error. If I rename the directory to shop, everything works fine.

My base_urls are set to `http://mydomain.com/shop` and I've tried rebuilding all the indexes. Why isn't this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `RewriteBase` in `magento/.htaccess` set correctly?